“If this isn't where I belong, then I don't know where is.” is this sentence correct?
I was inspired by the phrase “If this isn't Xxx, then I don't know what is.”, but is this one  correct? Thank you!

No. In the originating phrase, what does not match Xxx (which may well be a place, but can be many other things too.) It matches this. If we add the nouns for clarity, we would get If this place isn't where I belong, then I don't know what place is. You can't replace that with where place.

It would be perfectly understandable, but could be better expressed.

It’s understandable but not grammatically correct. “where I belong” is functioning as a noun here. The original phrase is using “what” to reference other noun options, what could be but we “don’t know” them. Even if that noun is a place, we use what to refrence them. I can show it much better than I can define it, sorry:
If this isn’t the place where I belong, then I don’t know what is [the place where I belong]. CORRECT
If this isn’t the place where I belong, then I don’t know where is [the place where I belong]. Grammatically INCORRECT

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
